# org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: unexpected type (position:END_DOCUMENT null@1:1 in Android KSOAP2, but in C# it's working

Tags: android, ksoap2

I've been experiencing this error for 2 weeks already when accessing the WCF (.svc) Web Service. But in C# when I added the web service as service reference, it works.

```
org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: unexpected type (position:END_DOCUMENT null@1:1 in     java.io.InputStreamReader@418188c0)
```

The Web Service's `targetNamespace=""urn:data.link.abc"` and the method's details is

```
<wsdl:operation name="EncryptPassword">
<wsdl:input wsaw:Action="EncryptPassword" name="EncryptPasswordRequest" message="tns:EncryptPasswordRequest"/>
<wsdl:output wsaw:Action="urn:data.link.abc/ABCContract/EncryptPasswordResponse"     name="EncryptPasswordReply" message="tns:EncryptPasswordReply"/>
</wsdl:operation>
```

This is my code for accessing the .svc web service.

```
public final String web_serviceEncryptPassword(String password)
{
    String NAMESPACE = "urn:data.link.abc";
    String METHOD_NAME = "EncryptPassword";
    String SOAP_ACTION =  NAMESPACE + "/" + "EncryptPassword";
    String URL = "http://192.168.20.254:8081/Service.svc"; //"http://192.168.20.254:8081/Service.svc?wsdl";

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    Object result = null;
    try
    {
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        //request.addProperty("_Password", password);
        PropertyInfo propertyInfo = new PropertyInfo();
        propertyInfo.setName("arg0");
        propertyInfo.setValue(password);
        propertyInfo.setType(String.class);
        request.addProperty(propertyInfo);


        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        envelope.bodyOut = request;

        //They said they have an authorization, but same error still showed up when I added the header for the                 
        //Authorization...
        //List<HeaderProperty> headers = new ArrayList<HeaderProperty>();
        //String authentication = android.util.Base64.encodeToString(
        //         "user.a:password".getBytes(), android.util.Base64.NO_WRAP);
        //headers.add(new HeaderProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + authentication));
        //// headers.add(new HeaderProperty("Authorization", "user.a:password"));

        androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);//, headers);
        SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
        result = Boolean.parseBoolean(response.getProperty(0).toString());

    }
    catch (Exception E)
    {
        E.printStackTrace();
    }

    return result.toString();
}
```

I'm using ksoap2-android-assembly-2.5.7-jar-with-dependencies.jar as my KSOAP2 library.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem changed below line as (ver1.2) and problem was solved

```
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
```

Answer (score 0):

this most likely means that the server responds with an http error. ksoap cannot parse http errors.
we have added this capability manually to the library.